# Soft delete implementation in C# - with minimal cost in terms of performance

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a field "DeletedOn" in User table. Once a user is deleted this field is updated. So all other operations like log in or assigning some role checks if the user is NOT deleted to perform that operation (Which is a costly approach)

I would expect some better idea so that the performance of the application is improved.

Comment: Maybe have a table with only deleted users and just move deleted user from the table to the deletedUsers table

Comment: The UserId (PrimaryKey) of one table will be the ForeignKey of another table, so I think that would not work - This is what I suppose

Comment: Why do you think that's costly? will take same effort to query for a nonexisting user than querying for an existing user with a basic where or ask for DeletedOn on memory...

Comment: Yes, but for every function it is being checked, so that is what my concern is, say there are 100 places where User table is used, then for those 100 places I need to make a  check, this is what I'm considering to be costly.

Comment: If this is SQL Server you could add filtered indexes.  But first test if this is _actually_ an issue.  As @GuidoZanon notes, a checking the deleted status in query like `select * from users where id = @id and deleted is null` will not really add any cost to the query.

Comment: Just put a service/DAL/facade with a method that return the user is exists and DeletedOn is null. Use that service/DAL/Facade from the houdred places that u need to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [EFCore's global query filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of querying it every time you can create a view or stored proc(returning a simple Deleted Yes/No) for the users related option.

Note : Stored Procs are faster when compared to views(depending on number of tables involved)